# returning and displaying a function value

Tags: java

```
static int countChars( String str, char searchChar ) {
    // Count the number of times searchChar occurs in
    // str and return the result.
    int i;     // A position in the string, str.
    char ch;   // A character in the string.
    int count; // Number of times searchChar has been found in str.
    count = 0;
    for ( i = 0;  i < str.length();  i++ ) {
        ch = str.charAt(i);  // Get the i-th character in str.
        if ( ch == searchChar )
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I'm trying to print out the the value from the function that counts the number of characters that occur in the string, but I'm not sure how to do this from the main function.

Comment: Did you try System.out.println(searchChar +" is "+ count +" times in "+ str); or System.out.println(searchChar +" is "+ countChars(str, searchStr) +" times in "+ str)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main method should call the function:

```
String string = "whatever";
char searchChar = "w";
System.out.println(countChars(string, searchChar));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 String mySearchString="Stringtosearch";
 char ch='s';
 System.out.println( countChars(mySearchString, ch)   );

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = countChars("hello", 'l');
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(countChar("cheese", 'e'));
}
```

Side note: You don't need the ch variable in countChars, you can save some lines by also setting count to 0 on same line, and declaring i in the for statement. You can do it like this: (some prefer to keep the { } instead of doing for/if on same line though)

```
public static int countChar(String str, char c)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) if(str.charAt(i) == c) count++;
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the return value to a variable:

```
String myString = "Count up the u's!";
char myChar = 'u';
int val = countChars(myString, myChar);
System.out.println(val);
```

or you could put the method in the println method:

```
System.out.println("Count up the u's!", 'u');
```

Check out the Javadocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(int)
The println() method can print literals of Strings or any primitive data type. Hope this helps :)